# What is a typical room cleaning tip in Montreal?

Tags: hotels, tipping, montreal

This fall, I will be traveling for work and staying in a relatively nice hotel in Montreal for six nights.

I've never stayed this long in a hotel before.

Is a tip for room cleaning expected in Montreal? If so, how much is usual?

Answer (score 2):

I typically don't tip in hotels since I keep my room organized and clean and I often skip room make up service altogether. Some hotels now offer an incentive for skipping: either a voucher or some charity donation for something "environmental". Most rooms have plenty of towels & supplies to restocking everything each day seems like a waste.

So unless there is significant clean up work, I'd keep it a $2/day for the days of actual service.

Comment: So do you tip or do you usually tip $2/day? A little confused. I've seen hotels do that, but it's usually just "please don't request a new towel." I've never seen a monetary incentive.

Comment: @AzorAhai: I've seen both a credit in loyalty points or some donation to charity as an incentive. There is typically a sign that you should hang outside your door before midnight or something like this. If I don't use the service I don't tip.